# What is the approach to solve spoj KPMATRIX?

Tags: dynamic-programming, sub-array, fenwick-tree

The problem link is [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/KPMATRIX/). The problem is basically to count all such sub matrices of a given matrix of size N by M, whose sum of elements is between A and B inclusive. N,M<=250. 10^-9<=A<=B<=10^9.

People have solved it using DP and BIT. I am not clear how.

First, i tried to solve a simpler version, 1-D case of the above problem:  Given an array A, of length N,  count all subarrays, where sum of elements in the subarray lies between A and B, but still couldn't think of better than O(n^2). Here is what i did :

I thought of making another array for keeping prefix sum of the original array, say prefix[N]. prefix[i] = A[1](http://www.spoj.com/problems/KPMATRIX/) + A[2] + A[3] + ...A[i]. set prefix[ 1] = A [ 1]. Then for each i from 2 to N, problem is to count all j <= i such  that sum Z = A[j] + A[j+1] + ..A[i] lies between A and B. This is equivalent to prefix[i] - prefix[j-1]. But it's still O(n^2), as for each i, j is hitting i places.

can anybody help me step by step to advance me in the given approach to solve the main problem ?.